# QueryParams not changing URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-query-params

I am currently trying to set queryParams using transitionTo. For whatever reason, when I try to set queryParams, nothing happens (my URL remains the same).

My code looks like this:

routes/recipes/index.js:

```
    actions: {

    ingredientQuery (query) {
        console.log(query);
        this.transitionTo({ queryParams: { ingredients: query }});
    }

}
```

When the action is triggered, sure enough I get the correct query value, but that's it. In case it matters, I'm on Ember v 1.13.8

Comment: Which route is your transitionTo taking you to? In your corresponding controller which gets called out needs to have properties defined:  queryParams: ['query_param1, query_p2','],
    query_param1: null, query_p2: null

Comment: I don't actually want it to take me to another route - just to set the parameters which I can then pass to my model

Comment: please post the current route url and the route url desired and the controlelr params

Comment: Can you setup demo on ember-twiddle or post full code of your controller/route?